# Divio Cloud local Docker database connection

Tags: python, django, database, docker, divio

I am a noob and I am trying to create a website following the tutorial from this guy: http://support.divio.com/academy/basic-how-to-build-a-website-and-blog-with-django-cms-60-minutes/introduction. It looks like I am stack at the part which I setup the local server of my project. When I do this a message appears on the power shell which says:

```
Waiting for local database server Couldn't connect to database container. 
Database server may not have started.
```

I tried to find where the database is located but I couldn't do it. Does it have to do that I am using a windows OS and Linux containers?

Comment: What has this got to do with programming? Where is your code?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes. I contacted Divo and they helped me with the solution. Unfortunately it was long time ago and i do not remember the way i did it,

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the database container is running locally by running:

```
docker ps
```

You should see a database container listed in the output:

```
... example_db_1
```

You can check if the correct database is available and contactable from the web container with:

```
docker-compose run --rm web psql -h postgres -U postgres db
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and Divio support got back to me within just a few minutes to fix it.

Their fix was to basically to delete two lines from `docker-compose.yml` in your project directory so it reads:

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    build: "."
    links:
      - "db:postgres"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app:rw"
      - "./data:/data:rw"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    env_file: .env-local

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app:rw"
```

Then download the database again and restart the project.  Hope that helps, and if not I can highly recommend contacting Divio support through their chat (bottom right of [this page](https://www.divio.com/get-help/)).

Comment: This will solve a problem for Windows/Linux users, when you have an error `FATAL: data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" has wrong ownership `; however I am not certain it will help in the case of `Waiting for local database server`.